# old sms read from smpp

Tags: php, sms, smpp

i am using smppclient.php for send and receiving the sms from my tcp/openssl smpp server

i am read only unread(latest) sms only

how can i read old sms from smpp server using php

I have a project coming up where I need to send and receive messages through a specific mobile operator, which only provides an SMPP interface. The whole project will be a hosted website. I have already read quite a lot, but I do not yet quite understand what is actually needed from my side to use the protocol.

Should my application try to maintain a constant connection to the smpp? Can I simply connect, send a message and then disconnect?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 questions here:

1. I think you don't get how the SMSC works, it will not keep "read SMS". It will store messages being sent until they are delivered to mobile (MS) or partners like you (SP/CP). Once a message is delivered to your server or to a mobile station, it is deleted on the SMSC.
2. If you work with a mobile operator, usually you should maintain your SMPP connection up all the time otherwise it will be considered as downtime from their end.

You can find quite a lot of documentation about Kannel that gives you examples with interactions in php.